# Statement.executeQuery does not return any results when using fuctions

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

If I run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE` in SQL console (i am using Oracle XE 11g) I get correctly one record as a result:

```
  COUNT(*)
----------
       695
```

But if I use the same query in Java for Statement I get no records in the result set, the same happens for another functions like "MAX".

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE");
if (rs.next()){
   count = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

No exception was throws and the method `rs.next()` returns false. I've tried ojdbc14 and ojdbc6 libs with no difference. Can anybody help?

Comment: What version of the jdbc driver are you usin?

Comment: I've tried both ojdbc14 and ojdbc6.